# Hierarchical data stage large data set extract with rest api

Tags: rest, datastage

How can the hierarchical data stage be used when extracting (GET) large data sets through rest api?  Previously we've done it in java, python etc. and looped on an offset.  Can this be done in the hierarchical datastage at all?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Rest Calls can be done from Hierarchical stage . by providing the URL and proper id and password for (authentication). But if there are multiple requests , hierarchical stage must be called in loop .